# Fortune 500 companies websites sitemap

Tags: research, business, companies

What is a good source, or approach, to collate a list of Fortune 500 companies websites sitemap URL (either to sitemap.xml or their sitemap webpage)?

Comment: Seems to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10232774/2327328